# Upgraded Synology NAS to DSM 7 and now mount cifs gives permission denied

Tags: nas, synology-diskstation

I have upgraded my Synology DS918+ to DSM version 7.1-42661.

Previously this command (ubuntu 18.04) worked fine:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.7/dir -o username=my_username,password='my_password',uid=1000,sec=ntlm,vers=1.0 /local_dir
```

Now, this gives "permission denied."

I have diagnosed using the NAS logs that this is because NTLM version 1.0 is no longer supported.

I have also tried

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.7/dir -o username=my_username,password='my_password',uid=1000 /local_dir
```

which gives "mount error(95): Operation not supported",

and

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.7/dir -o username=my_username,password='my_password',uid=1000,sec=ntlm,vers=2.0 /local_dir
```

Which gives "mount error(2): No such file or directory"

I have verified that the account settings I am using are still valid.
I can connect to the DSM web interface and no issues are reported.
I have added my IP address to the NFS settings for this shared folder in the DSM.

I do not get log entries for these requests in the NAS logs, which leads me to believe that Operation not Supported and Permission Denied may be linux/ubuntu errors rather than on the NAS side.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After examining the output of DMESG and googling for other options, I have found that

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.7/dir -o username=my_username,password='my_password',uid=1000,sec=ntlmssp,vers=2.0 /local_dir
```

worked.  There was no error message and after mounting I was able to successfully list the contents of the NAS.

In general it appears that a reasonable approach to trying to solve problems of this nature is to try combinations of

sec= in [leave out, ntlm, ntlmssp]
ver= in [1.0, 2.0, 2.1, 3.0, 3.02, 4.0]

And see if any work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).